# feedback in switching voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, feedback

I need to design a switching voltage regulator, all parts work fine but I am having trouble figuring out the feedback, on the negative terminal of my comparator i have a triangular wave that cycles between 5-10 volts. on the negative terminal have have the output from the error amplifier. the error amplifier takes a reference voltage which is to be controlled by the user, and change it to a scale which can be compared to the output from the triangular wave.

I have tried many things but I cannot seem to get the feedback right, I will appreciate any and all help and suggestions.

below is a simulation of the circuit from OrCad and also from falstad.
i believe my trouble comes from the part circled in red.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp7bB.png)

Comment: There are no comparators in your circuit. Add some.

Comment: U1 should be a comparator with some hysteresis, I think.

Comment: U1 is an opamp  just in the simulation but i am using a comparator in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Go look up Type 3 compensators, which you'll need for voltage mode control. TI has a great article on them http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva662/slva662.pdf you're currently using type 1 which doesn't have enough of a phase boost for stability.

Edit:
Also, your error amplifier (what's circled) should have a constant voltage reference as opposed to a ramp. The op amp that it connects to after should have the ramp. Your current configuration changes the voltage set point constantly.